# how can a function that is not activated affect the website?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JS website . I have a function that change the website in a wierd way. even wierder the function is not even activated when this change occurs (happens right at the start, after the site loads).
How can that be?

I played around and noticed that if I use append() and not appendTo, it works fine.. still I want to understand what is the issue with the appendTo().

I am adding here the html relevant code, and the JS.
The problematic function name is "keepe".
Thanks for the help.

html code:

```
<div id="whole">


</div>
```

JS code

```
var shownikud=function (letter){

$('#kamatz').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-kamatz.png " >');  
$('#patach').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-patach.png " >');
$('#zere').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-zere.png " >');
$('#segol').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-segol.png " >');
$('#shva').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-shva.png " >');
$('#shuruk').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-shuruk.png " >');
$('#kubutz').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-kubutz.png " >');
$('#cholam').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-cholam.png " >');
$('#chirik').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-chirik.png " >');
if ((letter==='bet'  ) || (letter==='kaf') || (letter==='pe')) {                 

    $('.options-l').show();
    $('#l-kamatz').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-kamatz.png " >');  
    $('#l-patach').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-patach.png " >');
    $('#l-zere').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-zere.png " >');
    $('#l-segol').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-segol.png " >');
    $('#l-shva').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-shva.png " >');
    $('#l-shuruk').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-shuruk.png " >');
    $('#l-kubutz').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-kubutz.png " >');
    $('#l-cholam').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-cholam.png " >');
    $('#l-chirik').html('<img src="pics/'+letter+'-l-chirik.png " >');
} else {
    $('.options-l').hide();
}

}

//this function will sound the right letter with the right sound
var voice= function(zlil){

var v = '<audio autoplay><source src="sounds/' +zlil+'.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does   not support the audio element.</audio>';
//$('.options').text(v);
$('#hearit').html(v);

}

**//this is the problematic function**
var keepe = function(so){
var accumulate=so;
$(accumulate).appendTo.('#whole'); **//this option destroy most of the site functionality**
$('#whole').html(accumulate);    **//this option works good**
$('#whole').append(accumulate); **//this option works good**
}

var main=function(){

/* this section defines what is the letter that was selected*/
$('.options-l').hide();
$('.letter').click(function(){
    //$('.options').text('ok - this is a result of clicking on one of the html elements');
    var let= this.id;
    //just to see what was the selected letter $('#testing').text(let);
    shownikud(let);


    $('.zlil').click(function() {
        //$('.options').text('ok - this is a result of clicking on a sound  elements');
        var sound=let+'-'+this.id; 
        //$('#testing').text(sound);
        voice(sound);
        keepe(sound); //**this is where i call the function**
        });
    });







};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: unclear, and unclear ????

Comment: I just want to point out this is an HTML website you're building, in JavaScript. It's not a JavaScript website. So how does the function behave? What's '*weird*'? What is supposed to happen, what is the problem?

Comment: I assume it's throwing an error because of the `.` in `appendTo.()`?

Comment: If it is a copy and past of your code then you have a syntax error here `$(accumulate).appendTo.('#whole')` which would break your code.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies - yep I missed the "." and once i checked the console it appeared there. I will check it before asking in the forum next time. Thanks for the help - now it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

`$(accumulate).appendTo.('#whole');` **//this option destroys most of the site functionality**

You have a period after `appendTo`, which should not be there, and is probably what is breaking your code.
Also, I believe the appendTo method takes a jQuery object as its argument, but you've passed in a string.

Comment: The `appendTo` method can very well take a string, which is used as a selector to locate elements. Ref: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: If this answer sufficiently answers your question, please select it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks for the link, I did not know that appendTo worked that way.